# Unable to test PUT request without content-type

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I was wondering, how can I test a PUT request with a body but without Content-Type by using Spring's WebTestClient?

My test is as follows:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class StackOverflowTest {

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    void testPUT() {
        // GIVEN
        ...
        
        // WHEN
        webTestClient.put()
                .uri("/foo/bar")
                .bodyValue("<abc></abc>")
                .exchange()
        
        // THEN
                .expectStatus().isCreated();
        ...
    }

}
```

but then the client sets automatically the Content-Type to `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`. In general, this is good thing, but I want to test exactly that case (client request without Content-Type). I could use another client but maybe there is a way or a workaround which I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible using the `WebTestClient`. I tried several approaches on my own e.g. custom `ExchangeFilterFunction`, different ways to set the body, but always got the `Content-Header` populated.

What works however is that if you don't provide any `.bodyValue()` or `.body()` to your request, you won't get the header.

If you are curious which place populates the `Content-Type` header, take a look at the `writeWithMessageWriters` method of `BodyInserters`:

```
private static <M extends ReactiveHttpOutputMessage> Mono<Void> writeWithMessageWriters(
  M outputMessage, BodyInserter.Context context, Object body, ResolvableType bodyType, @Nullable ReactiveAdapter adapter) {

  Publisher<?> publisher;
  if (body instanceof Publisher) {
    publisher = (Publisher<?>) body;
  }
  else if (adapter != null) {
    publisher = adapter.toPublisher(body);
  }
  else {
    publisher = Mono.just(body);
  }
  MediaType mediaType = outputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType();
  return context.messageWriters().stream()
    .filter(messageWriter -> messageWriter.canWrite(bodyType, mediaType))
    .findFirst()
    .map(BodyInserters::cast)
    .map(writer -> write(publisher, bodyType, mediaType, outputMessage, context, writer))
    .orElseGet(() -> Mono.error(unsupportedError(bodyType, context, mediaType)));
}
```

There you'll see that the `MediaType` is always retrieved from the message.

I guess it should work with the `TestRestTemplate` instead.